# Margin and Padding issues in IE7/8

Tags: wordpress, css

I have a search box using a mixture of floats of form/select elements.

The search is rendering fine in firefox, chrome, safari etc however IE8 is ignoring the margin and padding rules (tried both).

see here: http://property.begbies-traynor.com

The section in question is immediately below the slider, the search area.

When viewed in chrome for example, the Search submit button is correctly sitting just inside the main container whereas IE has it right up against the side.

Similarly, the Select elements are sat on top of each other despite there being adequate margin rules to separate them from each other.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also not working in any other browser not using the Webkit-engine (I've tested it in Opera and Firefox), as you are only including the padding- and margin-styles for Webkit:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* … */
}
```

If you want to see your CSS properties working in any browser, you should define them for any browser.